# unable to play RTSP url in videoView

Tags: java, android, streaming, android-videoview, rtsp

I am trying to play a RTSP url in videoView, but i am getting a popup saying that cannot play this video. I am using below code for playing RTSP url in videoView

```
link = "rtsp://mobilestr3.livestream.com/onDemand/ls/mashable/flv_d333a646-94aa-4035-a66e-1185bd885622";
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(link);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

I am new to android, i don't know where i am doing wrong. Please any one help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**go with this way**

Here is [setup link](http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/stream-rtmp-live-android/) to play video